# How to store non-git credentials in Openshift for a Tekton pipeline?

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

I have a Tekton pipeline that will be posting to a rest API. I need to pass credentials to this, but as far as I can tell from [this documentation](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/auth/), the only options for a pipeline are Git and Docker authentication? How would I securely store username/password credentials that I can pass into a pipeline to ultimately convert to Basic Auth for the rest request?